# Fetch with cookie not working even with `credentials: 'include'`

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, cookies, fetch

I can't get fetch to send a cookie. I [read](https://github.com/github/fetch#sending-cookies) that for cross origin request, you must use `credentials: 'include'`. But this still isn't giving me cookies.

### Fetch html document

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>fetch on load</div>
    <script>
      fetch('http://localhost:4001/sayhi', { credentials: 'include' })
        .then((res) => {
          return res.text();
        })
        .then((text) => {
          console.log('fetched: ' + text);
        })
        .catch(console.log);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Server file:

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.path);
 
  // this will log a cookie when several 
  // requests are sent through the browser 
  // but 'undefined' through `fetch`
  console.log('cookie in header: ', req.headers.cookie);
  
  next();
});

app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'very secret 12345',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
  })
);

app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`${req.method}: ${req.path}`);
  try {
    req.session.visits = req.session.visits ? req.session.visits + 1 : 1;
    return next();
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});

app.get('/sayhi', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('hey');
});

(async () =>
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/oneSession', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: true,
  }))()
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`Connected to MongoDB set user test`);
    app.listen(4001).on('listening', () => {
      console.log('info', `HTTP server listening on port 4001`);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

The middleware that runs `console.log('cookie in header: ', req.headers.cookie);` returns undefined for every fetch request.

Every fetch request is also creating a new session, I believe because the cookie isn't being set.

How can I get cookies to send with fetch?

### Update: Partial answer

I think adding these helped so far:

```
//instead of app.use(cors());
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: 'http://localhost:5501', // your_frontend_domain, it's an example
  })
);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
   `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);   
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:5501');` // your_frontend_domain, it's an example
   next()
});
```

But I still have a problem:

In devtools, I went to 'Network' and refreshed the html file to send the request again. There I saw the response headers. I could see that the Set-Cookie header was sent but had a yellow triangle warning.

[image]

It says to set `sameSite` to `true`.

I needed to add `cookie: { sameSite: 'none' }` to the session options

```js
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'very secret 12345',
    resave: true,
    cookie: { sameSite: 'none' },
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
  })
);
```

After I did that I got a new yellow triangle warning by the cookie that said I needed to set another option on cookie- `secure: true`. But this means only requests that send over HTTPS will work. But I'm in development and can't send over https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an example for your.
You don't need to setup "none" for sameSite attribute.

```js
{
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false,
  secret: 'very secret 12345',
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
  }
}
```

### Frontend Server

```js
// server.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("./public"));
app.listen(5001);
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        fetch('http://localhost:4001/test', {
            method: "POST",
            credentials: "include"
        }).then(response => {
            return response.json()
        }).then(json => {
            alert('Received:  ' + JSON.stringify(json));
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Backend Server

```js
// other-server.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const session = require('express-session')
var sess = {
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false,
  secret: 'very secret 12345',
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
  }
}

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(session(sess))
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Accept, Content-Type")
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:5001")
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true)
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH")
    next();
})
app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.sessionID);
    req.session.a = "hi"
    res.json({a: 1})
})

app.listen(4001, () => {
    console.log('start');
});
```

Comment: This didn't work. Cookie is still undefined

Comment: And what is the origin you fill with?

Comment: `origin: "http://127.0.0.1:5501"` and I tried `origin: "http://localhost:5501"`. Maybe I'm not setting the cookie header right? I thought 'express-session' does it for you.

Comment: Does the browser console show any message? Could you use default session store to avoid other situation like mongondb is not connected?

Comment: There was: `Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:4001/sayhi' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5501' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
 GET http://localhost:4001/sayhi net::ERR_FAILED` So I added `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:5501');` into one of the middlewares. It got rid of the error but still no cookie in `req.headers.cookie`.

Comment: I'm actually getting a different result with each browser - chrome, safari, and fire fox. It works in firefox. In chrome I'm getting the set-cookie header now, but it's not actually setting the cookie. But in safari I'm not able to fetch at all.

Comment: What happen after you add AccessControlAllowOrigin? Does chrome console show another error message?

Comment: I added `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:5501');` and it got rid of some errors a while ago. I also set `    cookie: {  secure: false, sameSite: 'none', },` which got rid of a warning that I saw in the network panel on devtools. It warned that sameSite has to be set to none for cross-origin responses. But now it says "secure" has to be set to "true". But I can't set it to true because I'm in development and can't send the request on HTTPS in development.

Comment: @DashiellRoseBark-Huss I updated my answer, there is an example you could try.

Comment: This works, but I'm trying to have them come from different origins

Comment: What do you mean different origins? My example is from origin 5001  to origin 4001. Does it match your requirement?

Comment: Oh my bad! I saw them both as 5001. That works. I don't understand why it works when I run it from an express server like this but not when I run the HTML file from VSCode's live server on `http://localhost:5501` even after changing the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to match the live server.

Comment: This is no longer working. Now I get this error `Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:4001/test' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5001' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:5001'` When I change  the access origin to 'http://127.0.0.1:5001' it requested I set `sameSite` to `none` again.

Comment: I figured it out. I was navigating in my browser to `http://127.0.0.1:5001/index.html` instead of `http://localhost:5001/index.html``. And while it got me the correct frontend files it, it changed the origin to http://127.0.0.1:5001. If I then change the "allow origin" to 127.0.0.1 then I have to set sameSite to none again. But I don't understand why will work for localhost and not 127.0.0.1.

Comment: It only take domain instead of ip, you could look [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) and [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/origin).

Answer (score 2):

### UPDATE

The solution below worked when I was navigating on the browser to `http://127.0.0.1:5501/index.html'`. But if you navigate to `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` [Jack Yu's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65083778/fetch-with-cookie-not-working-even-with-credentials-include#answer-65085494) answer works.

---

I needed to add options in the `cors` call `{ credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:5501' }`. As well as as options on the cookie `{ secure: false, sameSite: 'none'}`. As well as set the `res.header`s.

```js
const express = require('express');

const session = require('express-session');

const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: 'http://localhost:5501',
  })
);

app.use(
  session({
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    secret: 'very secret 12345',
    cookie: {
      secure: false,
      sameSite: 'none',
    },
  })
);

app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, authorization'
  );
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:5501');

  try {
    req.session.visits = req.session.visits ? req.session.visits + 1 : 1;
    console.log('req.session.visits: ', req.session.visits);
    return next();
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});

app.get('/sayhi', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('hey');
});

app.listen(4001).on('listening', () => {
  console.log('info', `HTTP server listening on port 4001`);
});
```

This works on firefox. But it still didn't work on chrome because Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. Mine is set to `secure: false` because I am not sending over HTTPS for development. So I followed these instructions:

> You can completely disable this feature by going to "chrome://flags" and disabling "Cookies without SameSite must be secure". However, this will disable it for all sites, so it will be less secure when you aren't developing too.

[source](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/34237768?hl=en)

But it concerns me that there isn't a better solution. I don't want to disable `"Cookies without SameSite must be secure"` for all sites if there's a security reason I shouldn't.